# Show title of a field as the date of that day

Tags: mysql, date, field

I have a structure of a table as follows:

```
| tipo      | Lunes | Martes | Miércoles | Jueves | Viernes | Sábado |
```

But I want instead of showing Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ... Show the day of each week.

```
| tipo      | 2017-10-02 | 2017-10-03 | 2017-10-04 | 2017-10-05 | 2017-10-06 |
```

I do not want to put these data by hand in the select, if not get them by means of some.

I like similar pivot, although I don't know if pivot is the best option.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to create column names that aren't hard-coded. That means you have to write a stored procedure.

Comment: Sounds like Pivot with a date table is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the message. Well the procedure for what he thought but I thought that there might be an easier way to do it Pivot type, for now I will leave and as I have, thanks also to both.